# jQuery sends to e, which I can then use e.currentTarget to grab the element on the page. How do I then use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

a jQuery event passes me e.

I can then use: e.currentTarget which gives me the element

```
<input type=​"checkbox" class=​"list_completed_checkbox" id=​"list_item_completed_checkbox_81">​
```

But if I try doing e.currentTarget.fadeOut(); I get an error:

```
68Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'fadeOut
```

How can I use the element w jQuery? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the element with `$()` to get a jQuery extended element.

```
$(e.currentTarget).fadeOut();
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$(e.currentTarget).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery to bind and handle the event, you should use `$(this).fadeOut()` and let jQuery abstract away the browser differences (like using `srcElement` instead of `currentTarget`).